# What's wrong with this simple method?

Tags: objective-c, methods

It's a simple objective-c method to calculate score. I get the result of F for all 4 scores even though it shouldnt do that. What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void) updateLetters:(int)score andLabel:(UILabel*)labelName {
    if(score>=97)
        labelName.text= @"A+";
    else if(score>=94)
        labelName.text= @"A";
    else if(score>=90)
        labelName.text= @"A-";
    else if(score>=87)
        labelName.text= @"B+";
    else if(score>=84)
        labelName.text= @"B";
    else if(score>=80)
        labelName.text= @"B-";
    else if(score>=77)
        labelName.text= @"C+";
    else if(score>=74)
        labelName.text= @"C";
    else if(score>=70)
        labelName.text= @"C-";
    else if(score>=67)
        labelName.text= @"D+";
    else if(score>=64)
        labelName.text= @"D";
    else if(score>=60)
        labelName.text= @"D-";
    else labelName.text=@"F";

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int r1score=appDelegate.correctAnswersCountR1;
    int r2score=appDelegate.correctAnswersCountR2;
    int r3score=appDelegate.correctAnswersCountR3;
    int r4score=appDelegate.correctAnswersCountR4;
    r1score=(r1score/17)*100;
    r2score=(r2score/17)*100;
    r3score=(r3score/17)*100;
    r4score=(r4score/17)*100;
    [self updateLetters: r1score andLabel: R1];
    [self updateLetters: r2score andLabel: R2];
    [self updateLetters: r3score andLabel: R3];
    [self updateLetters: r4score andLabel: R4];

}
```

Comment: Have you displayed out the numbers you are actually passing into the method? The integer is coming from your AppDelegate, maybe they aren't being filled or passing correctly.

Comment: What is possible range of values of appDelegate.correctAnswersCountR1? I suspect that for values comparable (or less than) 17 you are hit by the integer division r1score/17. Infact if r1score = 5 then 5/17 --> 0 and if r1score = 10 then 10/17 --> 0. So 0*100 -> 0 and then your procedure returns "F". To fix it just replace 17 with 17.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(R1score/17)*100 Will always result in 0, because it's all integer math.

Try (score/17.0)*100.0

Comment: I guess we've all been there ;-)

Comment: Indeed. In Delphi, / always returns a floating point result, while div does integer division. I have been bitten by the C way many times. <g>